# react native app with nodejs as my backend and postgres as my database

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

I have successfully connected my nodejs backend and my PostgreSQL database to my ubuntu server. I have also installed nginx as a reverse proxy and it is working when i access the public ip address on the browser.

When i cd to my backend folder that contains my index.js and do sudo node index.js:

i get

`Server started on port 9000... Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result Database Connected...`

and on my IOS simulator, my posts and everything get loaded correctly.

My problem is when i close my node.js server and install pm2 and configure pm2 correctly when i try to load my IOS simulator an in-app error gets appears and nothing is loaded. (i copied everything from my local database into the ubuntu database, hence the same posts must be shown)

my pm2 logs show this:

```
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 4.5.1
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 12.20.1
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home/ubuntu/.pm2
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home/ubuntu/.pm2/pm2.pid
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/ubuntu/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/ubuntu/.pm2/pub.sock
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: Application log path : /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: Worker Interval      : 30000
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/ubuntu/.pm2/dump.pm2
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: 
===============================================================================
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:26:49: PM2 log: App [app:0] online

/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/app-error.log last 15 lines:
0|app   | WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
0|app   | WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
0|app   | WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/home/ubuntu/config
0|app   | WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.

/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/app-out.log last 15 lines:
0|app   | Server started on port 9000...
0|app   | ErrorSequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
```

Comment: ErrorSequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user "ubuntu",I guess you are passing wrong credentials to your db

Comment: @Shubh in my ubuntu server i am logging into my database and i can see the tables and all the data. what i think is happening is that my .env is not being read on the server for some reason.

Comment: yes right its taking the default value and i dnt think you have ubuntu as any user in your db

Comment: @Shubh when i cd into my backend folder in my ubuntu server and access .env all my data is there and i also have an ubuntu user in my db since when i use this code  `psql -d app -h app.vvdvdvdvdvdv.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U ubuntu -p 5432` and enter my password i get logged into my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is P2M caches env variables.
Try to update env vars with the following command

```
pm2 restart {app name} --update-env
```

**Edit**
PM2 does not load env from .env file. To tackle this task is easier with a [pk2 ecosystem config](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/) where you can place your env variables.

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "myapp",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        env: {
          "NODE_ENV": "development",
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: App name is the name of app you see in pm2 list. However you can also use pid of app instances, but then you need to execute this command for each app instance in pm2.

Comment: I have tried the following code then did `pm2 status` and still getting same error and also my react antive app still doesnt load

Comment: Are you using a config file for PM2 or are you using direct command pm2 start app?

Comment: Please before creating sequelize connection ad some console logs what are the values of env vars. Try also to access them from terminal: echo "$var name"

Comment: I dont think the sequelize connection is working on my ubuntu server. i just imported the database from the local database thats it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227885/discussion-between-eduard-hasanaj-and-kd12345).